# Apex trigger removes Delete Account permission

Tags: apex, trigger, account, before-trigger, after-trigger

I created the trigger below that inserts a campaign record when an Account is created. The code works fine but the problem is it has taken the Delete Account permission from the System Admin profile. I was able to delete Accounts before but now I can't do it.

```
trigger CreateCampaignRecord on Account (before delete, after insert, before insert) {
        
        List<Campaign> myCamp = new List<Campaign>();

        for(Account a : Trigger.New) { 
            
        // Validation rule
        if(a.AnnualRevenue == NULL) {
           a.addError('Annual Revenue Field Cannot Be NULL');
        }
        else 
        {
        // Create a marketing campaign when an Account is inserted
        myCamp.add(new Campaign(Name=a.Name + ' Campaign', IsActive = True,Type='Webinar',
                                BudgetedCost = 0.01*a.AnnualRevenue,
                                StartDate=System.today().addDays(14), EndDate=System.today().addDays(14)
                                ));
        }
        insert myCamp;
        }
    
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            
        // Prevent the deletion of accounts if they have related opportunities.
         for (Account a : [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN 
                          (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity 
                           WHERE StageName != 'Closed Won' OR StageName != 'Closed Lost') 
                           AND Id IN :Trigger.old]) 
            {
             Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).addError('Cannot delete account with related opportunities.');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you edited the question and changed it into a different question. Now the answers don't match the question. Please restore the original question and create another question that states the other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sander is absolutely right; you don't differentiate between before and after insert.

The best practice for creation of other records as a side-effect of any other DML is in the after phase since you then have access to the originating objects' IDs and are less likely to have your creation effort discarded due to other processing flagging issues. However, in after insert you cannot update the originating records.

As such you do need both before and after insert. I recommend updating your code thus:

```
trigger CreateCampaignRecord on Account (before delete, after insert, before insert) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            // Prevent the deletion of accounts if they have related opportunities.
            for (Account a : [
                    SELECT Id
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE Id IN (
                                    SELECT AccountId
                                            FROM Opportunity
                                            WHERE StageName != 'Closed Won'
                                                    OR StageName != 'Closed Lost'
                            )
                                    AND Id IN :Trigger.old
            ]) {
                Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).addError('Cannot delete account with related opportunities.');
            }
        } else {
            // Must be isInsert based on the events of the trigger declaration
            for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
                // Validation rule
                if (a.AnnualRevenue == null) {
                    a.addError('Annual Revenue Field Cannot Be NULL');
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Must be isAfter based on the events on trigger declaration
        // Create a marketing campaign when an Account is inserted
        List<Campaign> myCamp = new List<Campaign>();

        for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
            myCamp.add(new Campaign(Name = a.Name + ' Campaign', IsActive = true, Type = 'Webinar',
                    BudgetedCost = 0.01 * a.AnnualRevenue,
                    StartDate = System.today().addDays(14), EndDate = System.today().addDays(14)
            ));
        }

        insert myCamp;
    }
}
```

I have simply re-ordered and added more conditions to the processing.

Note that I recommend all this processing be put in a handler class, rather than inline within the trigger, to allow better unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger specifies: after insert, before insert

So it works twice for newly created accounts.

Comment: so what is the solution? should I remove one of it?

Comment: That would solve this problem. But why does the trigger specify both? That must have a reason. Simply removing one of them could cause other problems.